# Choosing real time azure services hdinsight Kafka or service bus?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, real-time, azure-hdinsight, azure-servicebus-queues

I am evaluating message streaming services on Azure. I want real time message processing service (Most reliable) where message carrying high degree of importance and data must not be lost. Basically I want to make available real time data transmitted from some third party cloud to the API I have hosted on Azure (I have exposed API to the third party so that they can send data).
Following are the options I worked up on.

1. Event Hub and IOT Hub are used mostly for telemetry data/events. So I am excluding those. Here message is carrying great value in my use case.
2. Service Bus or Kafka on HDInsight I am thinking to use.

Now, service bus is offering more features as compared to Kafka and also providing very good documentation about how to use it.

But on the documentation I couldn't find anywhere that service bus is used for real time processing. Where as documentation is available stating use kafka for real time processing.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/technology-choices/real-time-ingestion

Which should be the best service among above for my use case? Any other better option which I have not thought of?

Comment: service bus queues are not designed for streaming as such. the link you shared clearly states the options and use cases. Event,IOT hubs (internally use kafka ) are the best PaaS options for ingestion of messages. and you can write an eventprocessorhost to process the messages in batches. even if you want to queue the messages in servicebus you would then have to stream analytics, spark , storm etc for real time processing.

Comment: @Aravind Kafka Streams API would be a fine processing engine, no? The broker itself simply moves and stores data, and a different library needs used to process, I agree

Comment: it should work too. I would prefer event hubs but again its you to decide based on the requirements. or you can try a sample on both and do some sort of benchmark and decide.

Comment: @Arvind But event hubs documentation use cases suggests that it useful more for Telemetry data collection. Mainly events. But if you have use case high-value messages that can not be lost then you should use Service Bus. Please check below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services

In our case we want high-value message to be transmitted real time. That's the reason we initially thought of using Event Hub which we dropped and thought using service bus. But again, it is not serving the purpose of real time message delivery.